# Check if files from multiple filelists exist in given directory

Tags: python

I need to check multiple file lists and determine which files are present. I have tried this in the following way, although I think it can be done better. I wrote some pseudo-code below:

```
a_files = ["A", "B", "c"]
A_files = ["abc", "def", "fgh"]
a_file_found = None
A_file_found = None
for a_ in a_files:
  if os.path.isfile(a_):
      a_file_found = "B"
for A_ in A_files:
   if os.path.isfile(A_):
      A_file_found = a_
```

Comment: Can you please clearly explain your case with example inputs and outputs? Would be easier than some pseudo code that does not make any sense.

Answer (score 7):

```
import os.path

# files "a" and "b" exist, "c" does not exist

a_files = ["a", "b", "c"];
a_exist = [f for f in a_files if os.path.isfile(f)];
a_non_exist = list(set(a_exist) ^ set(a_files))

print("existing: %s" % a_exist)            # ['a', 'b']
print("non existing: %s" % a_non_exist)    # ['c']
```

Answer (score 1):

To determine which files are present in your list, you need to start with a blank list instead of `None`.

```
>>> import os.path
>>> def validateFiles(fileList):
...    filesPresent = []
...    for eachFile in fileList:
...        if os.path.isfile(eachFile):
...            filesPresent.append(eachFile)
...    return filesPresent
>>> a_files = ["A", "B", "c"]
>>> validateFiles(a_files)
['A', 'B']     #: Sample output
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import glob
>>> a=['A','b', 'j_help.py', 'pre-push']
>>> [glob.glob(_file) for _file in a]
[[], [], ['j_help.py']]
>>> a=['A','b', 'j_help.py', 'pre-push']
>>> sum([glob.glob(_file) for _file in a], [])
['j_help.py', 'pre-push']
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a **function** to avoid repeating the loops:

```
def files_exist(file_list):
    file_found = None
    for item in file_list:
        if os.path.isfile(item):
            file_found = item
    return file_found
```

And then you can pass all the lists you want to this function.

Comment: `file_found = item` will only return the last file found from the list, and overwrite all previously found. Might as well do `return item`

Comment: @smci overwriting is what he's doing in his original code, which is why i wrote it this way.

Comment: True but his pseudo-code disagrees with the spec "determine which files are present"... list/ list comprehension/dict would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You known that you can merge two `list` in python by simply using the `+` symbol?

```
> a = [1, 2]
> b = [3, 4]
> c = a + b
> print(c)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You could merge the two list you have and check each file if it exists and simply return a list of existing files. Let's define this in a function definition.

```
import os.path

def get_existing_files(list_1, list_2):
    merged_list = list_1 + list_2
    result = []
    for _file in merged_list:
        if os.path.exists(_file):
            result.append(_file)
    return result
```

Or if you only want to return a `boolean` if the first file in the list is found.

```
import os.path

def any_file_exists(list_1, list_2):
    merged_list = list_1 + list_2
    result = []
    for _file in merged_list:
        if os.path.exists(_file):
            return True
    return False
```